# Call to member function - Trying to load partial into email body

Tags: php, zend-framework

> My Error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function partial() on a
>   non-object in /var/www/vhosts/MYURLHERE/application/models/MailUs.php
>   on line 14

Line 14 -

```
$body = $this->view->partial('partials/postcardEmail/eform1postcard.htm');
```

In Zend, I am trying to load a partial as the body of text for an email I am going to send out. Can someone explain to me why Zend would NOT be able to see $this->view->partial? Is there an alternative method by which I can call the partial and put it into the body of the email?

TLDR:

> How do I put a partial into a variable so I can email it to some one
>   in Zend.

Comment: $this->view is not an object.  Try using var_dump() to print it out and see what it is.  Look for the keyword "new" to see if it has been instantiated.

Comment: Models don't have access to the view, you'll need to pass it into the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$body = $view->partial('partials/postcardEmail/eform1postcard.htm');
```

Like Mike B. said there is now Access to the View from an model, this works only inside an view script.

Comment: Mike B and you are correct. I put the view into a variable in the controller and then passed the view to my Model. Works perfect now. Thanks!